# Telling an Angular Reactive form to repaint?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

In this [reset password material stepper demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-22z5xv) in the first step the email is collected in a `emailForm`.

When `next` is clicked the `submitEmail` function sets the value of the `emailControl` to the email entered.

This is the code for that:

```
  submitEmail() {
    if (this.emailForm.valid) {
      const email = this.emailForm.get('email')!.value;
      this.confirmCodeForm.get('email')!.setValue(email);
      console.log('THE EMAIL IS: ', this.confirmCodeForm.get('email').value);
      this.onEmailSubmit.emit(email);
    }
  }
```

We can see that the control value `email` does have the `email` entered set through this logging statement:

```
this.confirmCodeForm.get('email').value);
```

However in the second step the form does not repaint, and thus the `email` field (Which is `readonly`) does not reflect the email address entered.

How do we tell the `confirmCodeForm` to repaint after calling `setValue` on the `email` control?

I also tried using `patchValue` like this:

```
      const email = this.emailForm.get('email')!.value;
      this.confirmCodeForm.patchValue({ email });
      console.log('THE EMAIL IS: ', this.confirmCodeForm.get('email').value);
      this.onEmailSubmit.emit(email);
```

And the control does have the entered email as its value, but the form does not repaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it was quite hard to read what you wanted to achive here. But I think I got it. You want to take entered email from step 1 and copy it to step 2 into email input and form value. Problem was, that control value was set with `.setValue(email)` but the html code didn't reflect value change because `formControlName` wasn't pointing to that.

I changed html for the second step `formControlName` to email and added `this.confirmCodeForm.updateValueAndValidity();` just in case (although last one is not explicitly required).

```html
<mat-form-field>
        <input
          type="email"
          matInput
          placeholder="email"
          formControlName="email"
          readonly
        />
</mat-form-field>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qfeglo?file=src%2Fapp%2Freset-password%2Freset-password.component.ts